# How to call non-exported functions of a DLL?

Tags: dll, reverse-engineering

I need to call (get) non-exported functions of a `DLL`. Unlike PE export table, non-exports do not have any table having entries for these. More over, all disassembler like IDAPro and other debuggers only show exported function names with decorated names (After Shift+F3 in case of IDA) and show all other functions like sub_000FF sorts of.

Any idea how to get and call non-exported functions of `DLL` programmatically? (`GetProcAddress` after `LoadLibrary` only calls decorated exported functions not designed for non exports.)

Comment: How do you know about the functions (prototypes) you need to call. Do have the sources?

Comment: Actually function signatures(prototypes)itself of all non exported functions are required of a DLL in order for making the calls. I am writing a debugger utility which needs to call and test these non exported functions. For calling we need to know function signature(in/out parameters which it takes), exported functions always undecorated before making the call(because we know their addresses and after undecorating, we get full signature) In case of non exported functions we dont know where these functions are, more over they are not decorated and not placed in any table(e.g export table)

Comment: Knowing about function signature(prototypes) is the first step and making them call is the second one. This is why we need all non exported function signatures first.but how...????

Comment: Do you really need to know the prototype? DLL's use stdcall calling convention and hence clears their own stack (they "know" how many arguments they got)

FARPROC WINAPI proc = GetModuleHandle("mylib") + <offset in dll>

Comment: @Usman: You seem to have confused topics.  The prototypes are not required for dlls, they are required for C and similar languages to compile.  The dll doesn't actually have that information anymore.  The DLL will also commonly inline/remove non-exported functions, so they might not exist to be called directly.

Comment: Well this matter has been solved via usage of Assembly routines..
and I extracted the address of functions usage of DIA SDK..
So, this issue has been resolved..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem myself after usage of of DIA SDK .

I collected the function address from there and then via assembly rotuines I am able to call the function directly.
Thanks everybody for comments.

Comment: He used `*.pdb` file that is debug database. It is always available, especially for production programs (non-debug)