# How to call MessageBox with GetProcAddress function?

Tags: function, call, dllimport, dllexport, getprocaddress

I want to call MessageBox() function in such way:

1). load needed library
2). get the function address
3). call it

So, for such aim as I understand, I should define new type with all types of arguments in MessageBox function.

It returnes INT and accepts: HWND, LPCSTR, LPCSTR, UNIT.

So I registred new type:

```
typedef int(__stdcall *msgbox)(HWND, LPCSTR, LPCSTR, UINT);
```

I have problems with calling such function. Does such way work for all functions or only for exported?
How can I call MessageBox exactly in such way?

Full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

typedef int(__stdcall *msgbox)(HWND, LPCSTR, LPCSTR, UINT);

int main(void)
{
    HINSTANCE__ *hModule = LoadLibrary(L"\\Windows\\System32\\User32.dll");
    msgbox *me = 0;

    if(hModule != 0)
    {
        me = (msgbox*)GetProcAddress(hModule, "MessageBox");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why are you declaring everything as a pointer?

[`LoadLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns an `HMODULE`, not an `HINSTANCE__ *` (it will work with the latter but it's always better to adhere to the documentation).

Similarly, `msgbox` is `typedef`'d to a function pointer type, so `me` is a `msgbox`, not a `msgbox *`.

The reason why `GetProcAddress` fails is because user32.dll exports 2 functions, `MessageBoxA` and `MessageBoxW`. When you simply call `MessageBox` in your code, macros defined in Windows.h replace it with one of the 2 actual function names depending on whether you're compiling for `UNICODE` or not. But when you're trying to directly access the exported function as you are doing, you need to explicitly specify which one you're trying to get a pointer to.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

typedef int(__stdcall *msgbox)(HWND, LPCSTR, LPCSTR, UINT);

int main(void)
{
  HMODULE hModule = ::LoadLibrary(L"User32.dll");
  msgbox me = NULL;

  if( hModule != NULL ) {
    me = reinterpret_cast<msgbox>( ::GetProcAddress(hModule, "MessageBoxA") );
  }

  if( me != NULL ) {
    (*me)( NULL, "I'm a MessageBox", "Hello", MB_OK );
  }

  if( hModule != NULL ) {
    ::FreeLibrary( hModule );
  }
}
```

Comment: don't you know how to call NON-exported functions in DLL? Thank you!

Comment: @user1131997 I don't think there's any way to do that

Comment: what do you think about this topic? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264699/need-to-call-non-exported-functions-of-dll

Comment: @user1131997 I think there's a reason it's not been answered, there's no way to do it :-)

Comment: there were comments above question. Wait! Let's think! What's non-exported function in dll? do they have entry point in address region? maybe it's possible with offsets do smth with them, what do you think?

Comment: about " HMODULE, not an HINSTANCE__ * ", doesn't HMODULE be an HINSTANCE__ *? #define preprocessor is just hint for compiler how to comiple, if you go F12 to look, what is "HMODULE", it will HININSTANCE__* in header, won't it?

Comment: @user1131997: Always go with the official documentation.  What if the next version of visual studio makes `HMODULE` not a `HINSTANCE__*` anymore?

Comment: @MooingDuck I have not think about such stuff! Thank you very much! Now , I undersstood!

Comment: Can you explain why the need for resolution operator before API calls?