# GetProcAddress returning NULL for RegDeleteKeyEx

Tags: windows, winapi, registry

I am trying to implement recursive deletion of Registry Keys for both 32-bit and 64-bit OS. As **RegDeleteKeyEx** is not defined for OSes lesser than XP x64 Professional, I am trying to use the function indirectly.

**Problem**:: Even on x64, the **GetProcAddress()** is returning NULL.

```
//Global Declarations 
typedef LONG (WINAPI * PFN_RegDeleteKeyEx)(HKEY hKey , LPCTSTR lpSubKey , REGSAM samDesired , DWORD Reserved );
PFN_RegDeleteKeyEx _RegDeleteKeyEx ;

//The code inside function
hAdvAPI32 = LoadLibrary(TEXT("Advapi32.dll"));
_RegDeleteKeyEx = (PFN_RegDeleteKeyEx)GetProcAddress( hAdvAPI32, "RegDeleteKeyEx" );
if( _RegDeleteKeyEx == NULL )
     printf("NULL\n") ;
```

Comment: Use "RegDeleteKeyExW" instead.

Comment: @HansPassant: Hardcoding the wide-char variant would be wrong if his code is compiled without `UNICODE` since he used `LPC*T*STR` in his typedef.

Comment: @HansPassant- Thanks mate for the help. I got the concept :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call MessageBox with GetProcAddress function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128148/how-to-call-messagebox-with-getprocaddress-function)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`RegDeleteKeyEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) isn't actually a function - it's a macro. Depending on whether you have `UNICODE` defined, the macro expands to the actual function name which is given at the bottom of the MSDN page:

```
RegDeleteKeyExW (Unicode) and RegDeleteKeyExA (ANSI)
```

So in your case, you probably want something like

```
#ifdef UNICODE
    const char RegDeleteKeyExSymbol[] = "RegDeleteKeyExW";
#else 
    const char RegDeleteKeyExSymbol[] = "RegDeleteKeyExA";
#endif

_RegDeleteKeyEx = (PFN_RegDeleteKeyEx)GetProcAddress( hAdvAPI32, RegDeleteKeyExSymbol );
```

This will use the appropriate symbol name depending on how your own code is compiled (with or without `UNICODE` defined).

Comment: Thanks mate...Your answer is the exact one and most accurate but Martin B already made the point clear. My code worked flawlessly. Your ans should be the accepted one but you were just mins late.

Comment: @user1696837: If needed, you can change which one you accepted.

Comment: @user1696837 Yep. You just need to check this other answer instead.

Answer (score 2):

Windows exports *two* versions of any function that accepts or returns strings: One that takes an ANSI string and one that takes a Unicode string. The ANSI version has an `A` appended to the name of the function, and the Unicode version has a `W` (for "wide" strings). The Old New Thing has [an article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/01/03/1404965.aspx) that explains this in more detail.

Since `RegDeleteKeyEx` has a string argument, you need to add the `A` or `W` depending on whether you want to pass an ANSI or Unicode string, i.e. you need to use `RegDeleteKeyExA` or `RegDeleteKeyExW`.

In addition, names of functions in third-party DLLs are often *decorated* in various ways according to the calling convention. (Windows system DLLs, however, do not use name decoration, so you don't need to take this into account here.) Again, the Old New Thing has a [good explanation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/12/57833.aspx).

You can list all of the exports of a DLL (which will show you the actual function names you need to pass to `GetProcAddress`) using the [`dumpbin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c%28VS.71%29.aspx) program included with Visual C++:

```
dumpbin /exports mydll.dll
```

Comment: Thanks mate...those articles are just the right explanation for the problem.

Comment: In fact Windows API function names are **not** decorated. If that was the case then it would be something like: `_RegDeleteKeyExW@16`. But it isn't. You really ought to remove that misleading text from your answer. The real answer is what Frerich said.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan- Thanks for the revealation.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks for pointing that out -- I've edited the answer to correct the mistake.