# Windows/C++/DLL: will function pointer offset (from DLL base address in memory) always be the same after a DLL is loaded?

Tags: c++, windows, function, pointers

Let's say I compile a DLL with a static non-member exported function.

Then in another application I load the DLL with LoadLibrary.

Then, I find the offset of the exported function from the base address of the DLL in memory (subtract function pointer from base address).

If I were to load the library again (on the same machine, or another machine, or on a different version of windows, or in a VM, etc) could I **reliably** expect to calculate the address of that same function with [baseAddress + previously-calculated-offset]?

Comment: If the function is exported, why wouldn't you just use `GetProcAddress()` to get a reliable pointer to it, instead of depending on an offset?

Comment: In this particular case I want to avoid calls to GetProcAddress and also want to avoid parsing through the function list searching for a function by name. I would like to simply cast the function using baseAddr+offset and want to know if that method would have any unforeseen caveats.

Comment: but why, exactly? You are going to be fighting the OS. Loading libraries and accessing their exports is a core feature, you should let the OS do its job. In any case, as long as you can ensure the same version and bitness of the DLL is used on all machines, then theoretically the offset will usually be the same. But I wouldn't rely on that. Exports are located via a table that the OS loader patches at runtime, so in theory different areas of the DLL might map to different memory offsets at times, since the loader knows where they are actually located so it can populate the table.

Comment: @RemyLebeau For example, a public function symbol that defined in pdb but not exported in dll.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10137815/3427520